# How can I query a model by if there is a subclass instance?

Tags: python, django, model-inheritance

I have these two simple models, A and B:

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(A):
  age = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, how can I query for all instances of A which do not have an instance of B?

The only way I found requires an explicitly unique field on each subclass, which is NOT NULL, so that I can do A.objects.filter(b__this_is_a_b=None), for example, to get instances that are not also B instances. I'm looking for a way to do this without adding an explicit silly flag like that.

I also don't want to query for all of the objects and then filter them in Python. I want to get the DB to do it for me, which is basically something like `SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.id in (SELECT id from B)`

Comment: WHERE A.id *not* in (SELECT...), I think?

Answer (score 2):

Since some version of django or python this works as well:

```
A.Objects.all().filter(b__isnull=True)
```

because if a is an A object a.b gives the subclass B of a when it exists

I Know this is an old question, but my answer might help new searchers on this subject.

see also:

[multi table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

And one of my own questions about this: [downcasting a super class to a sub class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821935/django-model-inheritance-create-a-subclass-using-existing-super-class)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to do this purely in the DB with Django's
ORM, in a single query. Here's the best I've been able to do:

```
A.objects.exclude(id__in=[r[0] for r in B.objects.values_list("a_ptr_id")])
```

This is 2 DB queries, and works best with a simplistic inheritance
graph - each subclass of A would require a new database query.

---

Okay, it took a lot of trial and error, but I have a solution. It's
ugly as all hell, and the SQL is probably worse than just going with
two queries, but you can do something like so:

```
A.objects.exclude(b__age__isnull=True).exclude(b__age_isnull=False)
```

There's no way to get Django to do the join without referencing a
field on b. But with these successive `.exclude()`s, you make *any* A
with a B subclass match one or the other of the excludes. All you're left with are A's
without a B subclass.

Anyway, this is an interesting use case, you should bring it up on django-dev...

Comment: I would accept this answer, but it doesn't seem like any answer is really "correct" in a good sense. I'll bring it up with django-dev as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with django, but it looks like you want the isinstance(obj, type) built-in python method.

**Edit:**
Would A.objects.exclude(id__exact=B__id) work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm trying to give the django ORM the right instructions to generate the SQL to do this for me, rather than filter them on the client side.