# Django model inheritance: Create a subclass using existing super class

Tags: django, inheritance, model

I'm using [multi-table-inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), and want to know how to create an inherited type from an instance of the superclass.

Using the example given in the documentation:

```python
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()
```

Now when you create a `Restaurant`, you automatically make a `Place`, which is fine, and the behaviour I expect and want.

But what if I make a `Place`, and later decide I want to convert to a specific type (like `Restaurant`). How do you create a `Restaurant`, using an existing `Place`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django model inheritance: create sub-instance of existing instance (downcast)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064808/django-model-inheritance-create-sub-instance-of-existing-instance-downcast)

Comment: I saw that question and answer, but was confused because I thought that problem had to do with authentication (because a User is a bit more of a special object)

Comment: I upvoted your duplication remark, however... the question refering to is about Users, which might be confusing. I find this example of places and restaurants (stolen from the Django Documentations) more clear and resembling my problem.... but in base it's the same problem.

Comment: See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7623

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Multi-table inheritance is just `OneToOneField` relation between Place and Restaurant.

```
place = Place.objects.get(id=1)               

# Create a restaurant using existing Place   
restaurant = Resturant(place_ptr=place)
restaurant.save()
```

Comment: This will cause restaurant.name to be emptied. Because restaurant.save() will update the Place with name='' (because restaurant = Resturant())... there must be a better way...

Comment: You should add restaurant.__dict__.update(place.__dict__), see [Daniel Roseman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064808/django-model-inheritance-create-sub-instance-of-existing-instance-downcast).

Comment: Ok, the combination of the answer of secator and addition of jpic does the trick...

Answer (score 13):

```
place = Place.objects.get(id=1)

# Create a restaurant using existing Place
place.__class__ = Restaurant
place.save()
restaurant = place
```

Answer (score 9):

While undocumented, this seems to do the trick:

```
restaurant(place_ptr=place).save_base(raw=True)
```

This solves the problem without using any hacks and is the shortest solution, also in terms of processing, using Django APIs.

While searching for this solution, I also found a slightly longer one, but using documented APIs. It is basically the same as [Mariusz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822264/1760858), also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088221/1760858) for more details:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

restaurant(place_ptr=place, **model_to_dict(place)).save()
```

However, this second one is more risky due to limited field set returned by the model_to_dict (see again the answer explaining the differences among various methods presented). Naturally, it also generates more DB calls because it writes to both tables.

Comment: `restaurant(place_ptr=place).save_base(raw=True)`
Worked like a charm, thank you!