# Django workflow to convert model superclass to subclass

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django project with two models: Applicant and Client, where Client is a subclass of Applicant. I would like some way of allowing a user to add an existing Applicant instance as a Client. I already have a view for Applicant instances, so I thought that having a Client model form on that page would do this, but from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) it does not look like you can initialize a model form with an instance of a superclass. I know I could do this by having code that goes directly to the database and adds a field to the subclass table, but is there a more Django-y way of doing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a `Client` instance from an existing `Applicant` instance with the following code:

```
client = Client(applicant_ptr=applicant)
client.save_base(raw=True)
```

Comment: The code is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L486). Basically it does what you want- it forces django to create the correct record in the subclass's table without creating a new `Applicant`.

Comment: I recommend you to have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821935/django-model-inheritance-create-a-subclass-using-existing-super-class because you miss the client.__dict__.update(applicant.__dict__) Some of the filled in fields might be lossed if you forget this.

Comment: @michel.iamit, the `__dict__.update(applicant.__dict__)` hack is not necessary for this technique- that's why I use it.