# Derived model filefield not available

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I have a base model and derived model from it. base model is not abstract, so it also has table associated with it.

Problem : I create a base instance first and then derived instance. And associate derived instance to base. But I get `FileField` in my derived class as `None`, even if its saved and available in parent. Why so? Am I missing something?

Some sample code:

```
def get_filepath(instance):
     return u''+instance.name

def BaseModel(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     filepath = models.FileField(upload_to=get_filepath,
            max_length=255, null=True)
     #some other fields

def DerivedModel(BaseModel):
     type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

Sample on django shell:

```
>>> obj = BaseModel.objects.create(name='y')
>>> obj.id
56
>>> obj.save()
>>> obj.id
56
>>> nf=ContentFile("this is dummy text")
>>> obj.filepath.save('dummyfile', nf)
>>> dobj=DerivedModel()
>>> dobj.basemodel_ptr=obj
>>> dobj.save()
>>> dobj.id
56
>>> dobj.filepath
<FieldFile: None>
>>> obj.filepath
<FieldFile: y>
```

Update: for @dgel's answer:

- `save_base()` does it save the derived object? `dobj` does not get id after that.
- After `dobj.save()`, it seems attributes in base class are getting overwritten by attributes in derived class.
- I added `ctime` created time in `BaseModel` with default `datetime.datetime.utcnow`. So once I save derived object, `ctime` is updated to save time of derived object.
- When I look at the DB through *sqlitebrowser*, `filepath` field of the `BaseModel` row is empty.

---

```
>>> dobj.save_base(raw=True)
>>> dobj.id
>>> dobj.save()
>>> dobj.filepath
<FieldFile: None>
>>> obj.ctime
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 23, 8, 50, 3, 171573)
>>> dobj.ctime
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 23, 8, 51, 9, 946434)
>>> newdobj = DerivedModel.objects.get(id=dobj.id)
>>> newdobj.ctime
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 23, 8, 51, 9, 946434)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064808/django-model-inheritance-create-sub-instance-of-existing-instance-downcast

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dobj = DerivedModel()
dobj.basemodel_ptr=obj
dobj.save_base(raw=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I didn't find any documentation for `save_base`. Can you post some link?

Comment: In what way does it not work? I've used [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10641305/473232) many times to create a subclass instance for an existing superclass instance. It's not in the documentation, but the source is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/db/models/base.py#L467).

Comment: please see my update in question. Does `save_base()` saves `dobj` also in DB?

Comment: `dobj.__dict__.update(obj.__dict__)`, does the trick, found from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064808/django-model-inheritance-create-sub-instance-of-existing-instance-downcast